# Tkinter radiobutton indicatoron not recognised

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'd like my Radiobuttons to use the button box interface as mentioned on this page, by setting indicatoron=0:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm

Code snippet:

```
import ttk 

...

    self.selectedSectionCode = StringVar()
    self.selectedSectionCode.set("abc")

    abcButton = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='ABC', variable=self.selectedSectionCode, value='abc',  indicatoron= 0)
    abcButton.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(N,W))
```

However when I run my code I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\...\view.py", line 473, in __init__
    abcButton = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='ABC', value='abc',  indicatoron = 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 1073, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::radiobutton", kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 560, in __init__
    Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
clError: unknown option "-indicatoron"
```

I'm not sure why this is not working, and there are several examples on this site which mention this option used by the Radiobutton widget, by users who are also using Python 2.7.

Is there something missing in my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation you linked is for the `Tkinter.Radiobutton` class. You are using the [`ttk.Radiobutton`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_radiobutton.htm) class, which does not support an `indicatoron` attribute.