# How to make a themed tkinter Radiobutton sunken and raised?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, ttk, tkinter.style

So what I want to achieve is something like this:
[image: Radiobutton Example]

So I know this can be done in regular tkinter with `indicatoron=0` but this does not work with ttk or themed tkinter. Does anyone know how I would be able to achieve this with what I currently have:

`radiobutton1 = ttk.Radiobutton(labelFrameDegreesIncrement, text='1°', variable=varDegreeIncrement, value=1).grid(row=0, column=0)`

Also sorry if this isn't the form questions are posted here. This is my first time posting a question.

Comment: Try [STYLING OPTIONS `indicatorrelief`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_radiobutton.htm). Read also [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Comment: So I tried `indicatorrelief` but it came back with `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-indicatorrelief"`. Also I'm not sure how `ttk.style` is used according the documentation you gave. It seems that the syntax there is a lot different than what I'm used to.

Comment: With `ttk` you have to use `ttk.Style()` and `ttk.Radiobutton(..., style='MyRadioButtonStyle')`. See for ref [`tkinter.Style`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58201652/7414759)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter radiobutton indicatoron not recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247133/tkinter-radiobutton-indicatoron-not-recognised)

Answer (score 3):

> **Question**: themed tkinter Radiobutton sunken and raised?

Use the following `style options` to hide the `indicator`:

```
indicatorrelief=tk.FLAT,
indicatormargin=-1,
indicatordiameter=-1,
```

Use `style.map(...` to change the `background=` color according to the `state`.

- [map certain attributes to different button states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53104724/7414759)

---

- [STYLING OPTIONS](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_radiobutton.htm)
  According to the reference: **Some options are only available for specific themes.**

  [image: default] [image: classic]  [image: clam]  [image: alt]
  `default`          `classic`          `clam`                    `alt`

> To hide the `indicator`, using `theme` `clam` or `alt`, you need: `indicatormargin=-10`

---

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('ttk')
        style = ttk.Style(self)
        # style.theme_use('alt')  # 'aqua', 'step', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic'

        style.configure('IndicatorOff.TRadiobutton',
                        indicatorrelief=tk.FLAT,
                        indicatormargin=-1,
                        indicatordiameter=-1,
                        relief=tk.RAISED,
                        focusthickness=0, highlightthickness=0, padding=5)

        style.map('IndicatorOff.TRadiobutton',
                  background=[('selected', 'white'), ('active', '#ececec')])

        MODES = [("Monochrome", "1"),
                 ("Grayscale", "L"),
                 ("True color", "RGB"),
                 ("Color separation", "CMYK")]

        v = tk.StringVar(self, "L")  # initialize

        for text, mode in MODES:
            ttk.Radiobutton(self, text=text, variable=v, value=mode, width=15,
                            style='IndicatorOff.TRadiobutton').grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***